# SharePoint 2013 C# Event reciever choose specific template from document library

Tags: 2013, content-type, event-receivers, document-template

I have a document library with multiple content types of word templates.

In my event receiver I need to choose the right template based on a field of the modified/created list item.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is the event receiver running on items in the document library with the templates?  Or is it running on items in a separate list?

Comment: It is running in the document library with the templates

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do that as below:

```
...
SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["listname"];
SPContentType contentType = lib.ContentTypes["content-type-name"];
...
SPFile spf = web.GetFile(contentType.DocumentTemplateUrl);
...
```